# HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python

I've writtin this python script to get stock quotes from google finance. The script works as written however, if I enter a stock symbol that google does not have I get the HTTPError. I'm a beginner in python programming and not sure how to handle the HTTPError in the script. I have looked at other questions asked and none apply or able to help me in my quest.

```
import json
import urllib2

url = 'https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=%s' % symbol
lines = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().splitlines()
j = json.loads(''.join([x for x in lines if x not in ('// [', ']')]))        
bot.say('%s %s: (%s) %s' % (
        j['t'],
        j['l'],
        j['c'],
        j['lt']
 ))
```

Comment: `try: block_of_question(); except urllib2.HTTPError:print "There was an error"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your code within a `try`-`except` block and catch the error thrown:

```
import json
import urllib2

url = 'https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=%s' % symbol
try:
    lines = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().splitlines()
    j = json.loads(''.join([x for x in lines if x not in ('// [', ']')]))        
    bot.say('%s %s: (%s) %s' % (
        j['t'],
        j['l'],
        j['c'],
        j['lt']
     ))
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    pass #or do your custom error message handling here
```

Comment: I found I needed the except urllib2.HTTPError: Thanks